# Show restricted content in Help permanently

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

My problem is that for all pages in Delphi help I have to allow restricted content. This is frustrating and I ask for help how to avoid it. Se the recorded video on https://roland-gmail-5.tinytake.com/sf/MTY3NzQzXzEwNjEzOTE

I use Windows 7 as guest with VMWare WorkStation 10. IE 11 is installed and I suspect that it could be the reason. Maybe there is a setting somewhere to permanently allow show this content.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/75571/viewing-chm-files-across-the-network-in-windows-7

Comment: I don't know if David's comment helped, since that seems to be about .chm files, which D2007 does not use (it uses HTMLHelp 2 with dexplorer.exe) . I would recommend re-installing the help. Your help is installed in the same VM as Delphi is, right?

Comment: FWIW, does this also not work properly if the DevExpress stuff is not installed?

Comment: I'm also stuck using D2007. I find that it's more convenient to use the online help than the local help. I just use the [XE3 help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Main_Page) (no particular reason for using XE3).